# i want to update my current balance

Tags: java, netbeans

i can subtract it only from 85000. cuz  that value is  initialized. as an example lets say i do 2000 , it will be subtracted from the 85000 and gives 83000. the problem is if i do it second time , the withdrawal value subtract from the 85000 not from the 83000.how can i update my value .??

```
public class Withdrawal {

    private double amount;
    private double currentBalance=85000.00;
    double total;

        public Withdrawal(double amount1,double currentBalance) { 
               this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
               this.amount = amount1;
        }

        public Withdrawal(double currentBalance){
              this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
        }

        public Withdrawal(){

        }

        public void setAmount(double amount1){

            this.amount =amount1;
        }

        public double getAmount(){
            return  amount;

        }
        public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
            this.currentBalance =currentBalance;

        }

        public double getCurrentBalance() {
            return currentBalance;
        }


        public double getTotalAmount(){
            total= getCurrentBalance()- getAmount();
            return total;
        }
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see the code that's actually calling these methods.

Comment: Your not actually updating your current balance unless you are calling setCurrentBalance in your code elsewhere...If you want the current balance to be updated update it after you do a withdrawal...

Comment: maybe by changing the value of current balance somewhere? I don't see you doing it anywhere.

Comment: @MilanUdayanga is `getTotalAmount()` supposed to be doing the withdrawal?

Comment: I'm not too fond of the way you use the names. Sometimes, `currentBalance` is the function parameter and `this.currentBalance` is the class member, while at other times `currentBalance` is the class member. You can confuse yourself like that, so try to avoid it. Either always use `this.` for class members, or always use different names for the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused on how the objects are stored.

You're perfectly correct in thinking that a Withdrawal would have it's own object, but it wouldn't be used the way you think it should be.

Firstly, you probably need an account object to hold your money (A withdrawal doesn't hold money, it's a withdrawal!)

An account can be simple:

```
public class Account {
    double balance;

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
         this.balance -= amount;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
         return this.balance;
    }
}
```

The only reason for a withdrawal object would be to perhaps store the dates and the amount taken?

Comment: where should i have this code .and how can i link this with my Withdrawal code

Comment: where should i initialize the value for the account like 85000

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever setting the values of amount and current balance once, during the constructor.

*the problem is if i do it second time , the withdrawal value subtract from the 85000 not from the 83000*

make sure that when you're subtracting the amount (however you're attempting to do this) that you set the current balance to the current balance - amount

```
public void withdraw(int amount)
{
     this.currentBalance -= amount;
}
```

This way, when you call it again and it checks the value against the current balance, it will have changed to the value of the old balance minus the amount. So in your case it will be 85000-2000 the first time and when the withdraw function gets called again, it will access this.currentBalance which will have been set to 83000 from the last withdrawl.

Comment: How can i do it using arraylist